# How to populate a specific string based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, r, dplyr

Imagine I have this dataset

| Food |
| --- |
| apple |
| beef |
| orange |
| tomato |
| spinach |
| chicken |
| avocado |
| lettuce |

---

I would like to populate the Type of Food based on the food column, For instance, if any of the following values in the food column (e.g., apple, orange, and avocado), populate "fruit" in the Type column. This is the end result that I want

| Food | Type |
| --- | --- |
| apple | fruit |
| beef | meat |
| orange | fruit |
| tomato | vegetable |
| spinach | vegetable |
| chicken | meat |
| avocado | fruit |
| lettuce | vegetable |

---

In order to populate the Type of Food on each row, I tend to use the ifelse function as follow in R:

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate(Type = ifelse(Food == "apple","fruit",
                ifelse(Food == "orange","fruit",
                ifelse(Food == "avocado","fruit",
                ifelse(Food == "beef","meat",
                ifelse(Food == "chicken","meat",
                ifelse(Food == "tomato","vegetable",
                ifelse(Food == "spinach","vegetable",
                ifelse(Food == "lettuce","vegetable",Food))))))))))))
```

Using the above code, it still do the job and I have the Type of Food I want. However, if this is a dataset with a lot of rows, this method is not the best way to go for. So my question is: ***Is there a way for me to write a code, in which I specify that for any of the following values in Food (Apple, orange, and avocado), assign the type as Fruit, and so on and so forth with Meat and vegetables in R and Python?***

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a python component to this question? If so, I would use a dictionary to lookup the translation from food to type.

Comment: So you have a dataset that is already labeled and you want to apply those labels to another dataset? Because in the data you have, the Type is already there. I'm not sure I understand how the mapping should work. It looks like you might just need a join/merge but it's not clear what you are applying this transformation to. What exactly is the input and what is the output? Is the data you've shown the value of `dataset` in the code?

Comment: @JonSG not necessary. This is more of an R question. But I am also learning Python right now so I figure it would be nice if I know how to do the same thing in Python.

Comment: If you already have a dictionary, use a join.  If you want to create one, use `dplyr::case_match()`, the basic syntax would be `case_match(Food, c("apple", "orange", "avocado") ~ "Fruit", ...)`.

Comment: @MrFlick I just put the "Type" there for reference, that is the end result that I want. Originally, I would only have the "Food" column without the "Type" column. I want to use a code to make the "Type" column.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento That is an amazing idea! I will try it ASAP and let you know.

Comment: But you would need input data to match up food to type. You could write that in code, but I would instead recommend keeping track of that in a text file that you can import into R or any other programming language. That will make the mapping much easier to reuse. You are still going to have to type all the values at least once. Might as well put it in a useful format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into lookups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table

(Example in R: https://rpubs.com/pdbrown/lookup)

Create your lookup with the correct mapping and then use `left_join()` to patch it together.

```
library(tidyverse)

food <- c("apple", "beef")
food_df <- data.frame(food = food)

food_type_lookup <- data.frame(food = food, type = c("fruit", "meat"))

food_df %>% left_join(food_type_lookup)
```

The python equivalent would be `merge()` with the argument `how = 'left'` from pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This works!!!

Comment: Happy to hear that. If you find the solution satisfactory, please consider upvoting it and setting the checkmark for correct answer.

Comment: I would love to up vote, but my reputation does not allow me to yet. I am a new user. Sorry Lukas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with a named list for your lookup, then you can use `stack` for easy conversion to a lookup table you can join your data on. See example below.

```
lookup <- list(
  fruit = c("apple", "orange", "avocado"),
  meat = c("beef", "chicken"),
  vegetables = c("tomato", "spinach", "lettuce")
)
 
df <- data.frame(food = c("apple", "chicken", "apple", "orange", "banana", "tomato", "avocado"))

df %>% left_join(setNames(stack(lookup), c("food", "type")))

#      food       type
# 1   apple      fruit
# 2 chicken       meat
# 3   apple      fruit
# 4  orange      fruit
# 5  banana       <NA>
# 6  tomato vegetables
# 7 avocado      fruit
```

Comment: Thank you. This one works great as well. I really appreciate it!